# How to do ajax request and get response from Android Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new in Android Hybrid App. I want post token in ajax request and Get ajax response.

*My Webview is here*

[image]

In This webview 3 field post by ajax from php side but I want when click on **SUBMIT** button with this 3 field i want to post token from my side.

So how can i post token with this post request and also how can get Response of this request.

*This is my ajax Function:*

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: 'http://localhost/php_site/insertUserData',
                       method: "POST",
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: $("#form").serialize(),
                       success: function (result) {
                           console.log(result);
                       },
                       error: function () {
                           console.log("error");
                       }
                   });
               });
```

Above ajax post request code implemented in php file loaded in Android webview.

I try to find but can't get exact solution please help me if anyone know this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to post your `token` as parameter of **`POST`** request. For that you may have to create **PHP** file instead of **HTML** file.

like:

```
www.yoururl.com/functionName.php
```

with post parameter **`token`** which will be get by PHP file and **make one hidden** field to store it.

So your form will automatically post token by clicking on SUBMIT button.

I think it will be a better solution. If you find any then happy to know. :) :)

Thank you.